# How to find rolling daily average

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell

I'm trying to figure out daily disk usage on my servers, I have a powershell script that is writing to the following table every morning:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiskInfo_SJ](
[SystemName] [sysname] NULL,
[DeviceID] [sysname] NULL,
[VolumeName] [sysname] NULL,
[Size] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
[FreeSpace] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
[AddDate] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample data would look like:

```
SystemName  DeviceID    VolumeName  Size            FreeSpace       AddDate
ACSQL751    C:                      146799554560.00 84255379456.00  2014-10-13 13:16:52.910
ACSQL751    D:          LocalDisk   81586515968.00  75507929088.00  2014-10-13 13:16:52.910
ACSQL751    F:          SANVol2     156757352448.00 146196172800.00 2014-10-13 13:16:52.910
AEGISSQL02  C:                      73364254720.00  16627585024.00  2014-10-13 13:16:52.910
```

What I would like to do is come up with a script that takes the weekly average and projects when the drive would run out of data if the average is accurate.

Comment: Do you want this "script" to be purely PowerShell, or based upon a SQL query which does the moving average?

Comment: Powershell would be fine - I'm not sure what would be "easier"